# Is scale_x_chron broken in ggplot2 2.2.1 and R 3.5.0?

Tags: r, ggplot2, chron

If I run the example in `?scale_x_chron`:

```
if(require("ggplot2")) {
dd <- data.frame(tt = chron(1:10), value = 101:110)
p <- ggplot(dd, aes(tt, value)) +
         geom_point() + scale_x_chron(format = "%m-%d")
print(p)
}
```

I get

```
Error in as.POSIXct.default(x) : 
do not know how to convert 'x' to class “POSIXct”
```

Is the function broken? Should I install another version? I tried to update via rstudio update button (in packages) but no luck.

EDIT: chron version is `chron_2.3-45`

EDIT2: I have noticed that

```
as.Date(chronDate)
Error in as.Date.default(chronDate) : 
do not know how to convert 'chronDate' to class “Date”
```

It used to work back in R 3.4... 
I am having trouble to go back to previous versions of R, so this is really a problem for me..

Comment: No error for me on `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`, `chron_2.3-52` and R 3.4.0. Can you add your `chron` version?

Comment: I updated my question with more information...

Comment: updating to `chron_2.3-52` solved my issue. For some reason it was stucked to `chron_2.3-45` and "update" function in Rstudio (in Packages pane) did not detect the available update of `chron`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved now. Updating chron to `chron_2.3-52` solved everything.